# I cant get my batch mini-game to work

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have problems with this code, it should only perform an action when the correct input is given.

```
enter code here

@echo off

echo I want to play a game. Do you?

set /P INPUT=[Y/N]: %=%
If %INPUT%=="Y" goto YES
If %INPUT%=="y" goto YES
If %INPUT%=="N" goto NO
If %INPUT%=="n" goto NO

:NO
echo FOOL!
goto end

:YES
echo Good, good...
goto end

:end

PAUSE
```

But the input i give doesnt make a difference, also letters like "h" will trigger an reaction. It will perform the "NO" echo everytime. This is because its the first code after the choise section. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: What is `%=%` for? it does not make any sense...

Answer (score 1):

You missed the quotes:

```
If "%INPUT%"=="Y" goto YES
If "%INPUT%"=="y" goto YES
If "%INPUT%"=="N" goto NO
If "%INPUT%"=="n" goto NO
```

Else you compare Y with "Y".

Answer (score 0):

After

```
If "%INPUT%"=="n" goto NO
```

you need to

```
goto somewhere
```

otherwise, `cmd` simply continues processing, line by line, until it reaches a `goto` or `exit` or `end-of-file`.

`:somewhere` should be just before ypu `do you want to play` prompt.

BTW, you can use

```
if /i ".....
```

to make the comparison case-insensitive, and

```
"%input:~0,1%"
```

will return the first character of the string (so a response like "yello" will return `y`)

Answer (score 0):

Well in order to achieve what you want the following modifications are needed for that to happen.

Here is the original code you programmed:

```
    @echo off

echo I want to play a game. Do you?

set /P INPUT=[Y/N]: %=%
If %INPUT%=="Y" goto YES
If %INPUT%=="y" goto YES
If %INPUT%=="N" goto NO
If %INPUT%=="n" goto NO

:NO
echo FOOL!
goto end

:YES
echo Good, good...
goto end

:end

PAUSE
```

Here is the modifications that I made to the code to make it run more smoothly:

```
     echo off
     goto :menu
     cls

    :menu
    cls
    echo I want to play a game. Do you?
    echo[
    set /P INPUT=[Y/N]: %=%
    If %INPUT% equ Y goto :YES
    If %INPUT% equ y goto :YES
    If %INPUT% equ N goto :YES
    If %INPUT% equ n goto :YES
    else goto :NO

    :NO
    cls
    echo FOOL!
    pause
    goto end

    :YES
    echo Good, good...
    goto end

    :end
```

I am assuming that based on the question that you asked that you want the following inputs (Y,y,N,n) to generate a result and anything else will go to :NO section of the code? Your question wasn't really detailed.

Comment: Thats true, thank your for your reply anyways, That code runs a lot better indeed, but all the other inputs that arent "Y,N,y,n" should just shut down the program.

Comment: I edited the code and put the "Y,N,y,n" as :YES. Hopefully that helps!